# How to make a div cover all the page with CSS

Tags: css

I have a block which should cover all screen. This is the fade block, which appears after pressing the button.

```
.main-fade {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  
  background: $BACKGROUND_FADE;

  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

It works perfectly. Until the horizontal scrolling. After scrolling down the block ends and a user can see the space which is not covered by the block.

[image]
Image 1: before the scrolling all screen is covered by the block.

[image]

Image 2: after the scrolling down You can see the non-faded space which is not covered by the block.

I need your advice, how to make this block cover all posible space of the page or follow for the scrolling.
Thanks!

Comment: Try using `position: fixed` rather than `position: absolute`. This should keep the elements static on the screen as you scroll.

Comment: This css-tricks article might help you: https://css-tricks.com/prevent-page-scrolling-when-a-modal-is-open/

Comment: @thebrownkid, thanks a lot! "position: fixed" has solved my problem!

Comment: @nthnchu, thanks for answer. I'll read this article.